# Changing the colour of selectInput entries in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)

# Remove all numbered colour names
col.list <- colours()[!grepl("\\d", colours())]

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "col",
              label = "Colour",
              choices = col.list, selected = "maroon"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It creates the following ui control:

[image]

It's a list of all R colours (excluding the numbered ones).

Is it possible to make it that each entry is coloured according to the actual colour, instead of all being black?

Comment: See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/1DXjpB_uaRA).  Answer by Dean Attali, so probably reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `shinyWidgets` package where you an style it inside the `choicesOpt`. change the `background` argument to `color` if you want to change the color of the entries and not the background

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
col.list <- colours()[!grepl("\\d", colours())]
colors <- paste0("background:",col.list,";")

ui <- fluidPage(
    pickerInput("col", "Colour", multiple=T, choices = col.list, 
                choicesOpt = list(
                    style = colors))
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]